# How do I sort a list of dictionaries by more than one element

Tags: python

This thread [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary) explains very clearly how to sort a list of dictionaries.  In summary for,

```
[{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}]
```

You do:

```
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

However, I have much more elements in my dictionary and I need to sort by four of them - not just one.  Any tips how to do this?

Note: I read further into the thread and this suggestion:

```
sortedlist = sorted(input, key=lambda elem: "%02d %s" % (elem['age'], elem['name']))
```

does not work.  It gives error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be intergers, not str
```

I try various versions of this and to no avail.

Any help appreciated,

Comment: That actually works for me.  Are you sure you set input to `[{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}]`?  [Although I'd sort by the tuple itself, rather than the string.  Simpler and less error-prone-- say there's a 100-year-old.]

Comment: Very good doc at Python Wiki: [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change the key function to return a tuple containing the elements you wish to sort by:

```
newlist = sorted(input, key=lambda k: (k['age'], k['name']))
```

For example:

```
In [13]: input = [{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}, {'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, {'name':'Milhouse', 'age':10}, {'name': 'Mr. Burns', 'age': 104}]

In [14]: sorted(input, key=lambda k: (k['age'], k['name']))
Out[14]: 
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Bart'},
 {'age': 10, 'name': 'Milhouse'},
 {'age': 39, 'name': 'Homer'},
 {'age': 104, 'name': 'Mr. Burns'}]
```

Your approach with string formatting could also be made to work, but the number of digits in the format would need to be increased to accommodate the likes of [Cornelius Chapman](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Cornelius_Chapman). ;-)

Having said that, I would recommend using a tuple, as this tackles the problem more directly, is more efficient and is less prone to coding errors.

**edit:** As suggested by @JBernardo in the comments, the above can also be phrased using [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [19]: sorted(input, key=operator.itemgetter('age','name'))
Out[19]: 
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Bart'},
 {'age': 10, 'name': 'Milhouse'},
 {'age': 39, 'name': 'Homer'},
 {'age': 104, 'name': 'Mr. Burns'}]
```